# generic methods and wildcards

Tags: java, generics, covariance, contravariance, bounded-wildcard

What are the differences between the following three signatures?

```
static <T> void foo(List<T>,           Comparator<? super T>);
static <T> void bar(List<? extends T>, Comparator<T>        );
static <T> void baz(List<? extends T>, Comparator<? super T>);
```

---

I know what `extends` and `super` mean in Generics. My question is whether there is a difference between `foo`, `bar` and `baz`. Should I make one of the parameters invariant and the other one variant in the appropriate direction, or should I make both of them variant? Does it make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference is whether `T` represents the type parameter of the `List`, the `Comparator`, or something in between.

As far as the caller is concerned, the three method signatures are equivalent, i.e. whenever one of them can be used, the others can be used as well.

For the method implementation `foo` is probably most convenient, as it allows modifying the list without needing an additional capture conversion, which would require delegating to a helper method.

Comment: `foo`/`List<T>` makes more sense to the client as well. Almost certainly the type of the list is a much more significance than that of the comparator.

Answer (score 5):

PECS - Producer extends, consumer super.

To explain this "rule":

- `extends` means the genericized object produces elements of the type. When it's a collection, it means you can only take elements from the collection, but not put them in. The comparator
- `super` means the object consumes objects of the selected type. So you can *add* to the collection, but not read from it.
- the lack of extends and super means you can do both for the exact type specified.

Regarding the `Comparator`, I don't think it makes any difference. Normally, it would be `<? super T>` because you the comparator consumes objects, but in all three cases you can safely invoke `Collections.sort(list, comparator);` (the signature of which is `<? super T>`)

Comment: I know what `extends` and `super` mean in Generics. My question is whether there is a difference between `foo`, `bar` and `baz`. Should I make one of the parameters invariant and the other one variant in the appropriate direction, or should I make both of them variant? Does it make a difference?

Comment: it all depends on what happens in the method body.

Comment: Basically, the method body will probably refer to the type `T`, so the implementation of `foo` and `bar` will have to look different because they use a different `T`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `? extends T` means that the `List` may be generic of any type that is derived from T, whereas `List<T>` can only be a `List` of `T` and not any of its derived classes.

Comment: I know what `extends` and `super` mean in Generics. My question is whether there is a difference between `foo`, `bar` and `baz`. Should I make one of the parameters invariant and the other one variant in the appropriate direction, or should I make both of them variant? Does it make a difference?